# Why are my javascript arrow functions not working in Edge/IE?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, syntax-error, compatibility

I have a compatibility issue with my Javascript code in IE and Edge. It is not detecting arrow functions correctly within my classes.

So this throws an error in Edge for me, within a class:

```
class WebAPI{
  constructor(){}

  replayCSV = () => {
    console.log("test");
  }
}
```

And here's the error on Edge:
[Edge Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGskS.png)

And it's essentially the same error on IE, just errors on a different arrow function for the same reason.

I'm using arrow functions to take care of certain nested referencing issues, standard stuff.

You can see the full code here, it's all WIP stuff: https://github.com/moothyknight/HEG_ESP32/blob/master/HEG_WIFI_BLE_Lolin32/webDemo/HEGwebAPI.js

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported in IE. https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported by IE at all; if you need them to work in IE, you'll have to use a transpiler like Babel to convert them to ES5 for you. Edge does support arrow functions, but doesn't support class fields, only class methods (you would need to put your field into a constructor method, like `this.replayCSV = ...`). So your options are to use a transpiler like Babel, avoid ES6 syntax completely, or don't support IE/Edge correctly.

Comment: Simply not supported, you can look at transpilation for cross-browser support if you want to mitigate the headache. 

"It's not a feature, it's a bug! wait, did I get that right?" - IE

Comment: Use this: https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20functions . https://caniuse.com is a great source for answering questions about browser-feature compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow functions won't work in some earlier browsers such IE, Earlier versions of safari, etc. all ES6 code should be transpiled with babel or typescript before be used on these browser versions.